# From what country does iTunes payouts come from

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, app-store-connect

I'm a new iOS developer in Sweden and i'm gonna upload my app with in-app purchases to the App Store. The problem is that my bank requires me to fill out from what countrys i will be getting transfers from. 
So i wonder from what country my payouts will come from when my bank country, and upload country is Sweden?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. I’m a U.S. developer and have always received my payments in full, indicating that there was no exchange rate involved. The payments originate from Apple’s bank, which given this information, I would imagine is in the United States.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a developer from the Netherlands. I get payments from Apple Inc. from a Deutsche Bank account hold in Great Britain. Since the whole of Europe has switched to IBAN it's easy to deduct where a payments comes from.

By the way, it's always nice to see my bank-statement and find Apple is paying me something :-)

Comment: That sounds interesting. I'm also devoloping the same app for android and the Google company responsible for Google play in Europe is located in Ireland. I wonder if there are some good laws in the UK and Ireland that is good for companies with EU reach? Well thanks for the answer I will tell my bank England and then we will see if I ever get money from my app.

Comment: Most companies that do financial stuff in Europe are located in the UK. (which properly end because of Brexit) Apple has also a company in Ireland overseeing all European activities.